# spd-say change voice doesn't apply language

Tags: text-to-speech

When I am using

```
spd-say -l "en-US" -y Belinda "Hello sir, how can I help you?"
```

it works fine with the selected voice. However if I run the same command again it reverts to the default `male1` voice. Then after a few seconds I can use the selected voice again. I tried adding `-t female1` but that doesn't change. And also the `-w` (wait) parameter to no effect.

Do I always have to wait for some time before I can re-use a voice?

Answer (score 0):

I tried:

```
    sudo apt install espeak
    spd-conf --espeak
    spd-say -l "en-UK" -y Belinda "What do you want me to say?"
```

At least it doesn't change to default by itself.